# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and corrupt computer

Tags: software-installation, syslog

My computer is suddenly going to h+ll in a handbasket.

I have religiously used software updater; last week my UPS battery died, and since then we have had two or three power outages.  So when my sound got stuck on mute and the indicator constantly flashes and clogs up everything else, I put it down to a hardware, possibly motherboard problem.

But this morning I went and looked at the system log, and for quite a long time before the dead UPS, there are many, many entries for "half-installed" and "half-configured".  In fact, I'd say most of the updates were half installed or half configured.

What do I do now?

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` - does that help?

Comment: I just tried that and it made no apparent difference.